# /usr/bin/id: fork: Resource temporarily unavailable

Tags: zsh

Getting this error everytime I start a new ZSH session:

```
/usr/bin/id: fork: Resource temporarily unavailable
```

Any idea how to fix this? I'm running on Mac OS X Lion and zsh. Let me know if you need any additional details. Not sure when this started, so not sure what could've caused it...

Answer (score 2):

This usually means you have hit the limit on the number of running processes, and cannot start any more.
Note that this may be the system-wide limit, a per-user limit, or a per-session limit.  (I believe OS X only has a system-wide limit by default.)

[This question over on SuperUser deals with this issue](https://superuser.com/questions/276909/getting-bash-fork-resource-temporarily-unavailable-in-osx), but basically you need to figure out what has spawned so many processes and make it stop doing that.  Sorry I can't be more specific, but it's impossible for someone on Server Fault to tell you what is running on your system.